# Data getting deleted without being moved to trash

Tags: mount, ntfs, fstab, trash

I edited fstab to mount a ntfs drive (of order /dev/sta5) on a location of order /media/usrname/TheDrive for a systemwide mount. I used the following line

```
UUID=TheDrive'sUuid    /media/username/TheDrive    ntfs-3g     rw,auto,auto,user,fmask=011, dmask=0000    0    0
```

The mount was successful. Now Im facing a problem: whenever I delete any data (dir as well as file) from the mounted ntfs partition using nautilus, the data gets directly deleted without being moved to TRASH. The "Move to Trash" of files in this partition is been replaced by "Delete".

I tried the same on "/home" and "/" files and "Move to Trash" is available and even works as normal and data is sent to TRASH when clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the options you have used to mount the partition with `rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,uid=1000`, replacing `uid=1000` with the id of your user (you can get your id using `id -u`) so that the line in `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

```
UUID=TheDrive'sUuid    /media/username/TheDrive    ntfs-3g     rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,uid=1000     0    0
```

Files deleted from NTFS partitions are not moved to "Trash", they are moved to the `/media/username/TheDrive/.Trash-1000` directory. You will have a `files` directory here which will store the thrashed files.

`.Trash-1000` is a hidden directory. To see hidden directories in nautilus press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> when you open nautilus.

Comment: Nope, In my case they dont. If I try to deleate a file, I get a dialog box "The files will be deleted permanantly..." and thus, they dont go to trash and are deleted directly instead.

Comment: +if i locally mount a partition using nautilus the files go to trash as usual. Thus it a problem with system wide mounts only

Comment: @about99ninjas: Can you try remounting replacing the options with `rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,uid=1000`, replacing the uid with yours? You can get your id using `id -u`.

Comment: thanks.. It worked btw can u please tell me what was wrong with wy fsab options?

Comment: @about99ninjas: Not really sure, but that is how I have mounted my NTFS partition, will update if I find the cause.